# Json Serialize and Deserialize complex content using Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I have a structure that I want to store using JSON in a file. None of the implementation classes will have more significant information than what is given.

```
public class ItemExample implements IItem{
   private ModelMap map;
   private String name;
}

public class ModelMap {
   private HashMap<Coord, IPartType> map;
}

public class Coord {
   private int x,y,z;
}

public class PartExample implements IPartType {  
   private String name;                         
   private Purity purity;
}

public Enum Purity{
}
```

I am brand new to creating JSONs, I've been reading up on how Gson works but I am not really understanding how to translate the examples to my case. Most examples assume knowledge of certain aspects that I just don't know yet.

This is what I have started to do for IPartType:

```
public class PartDeserialize<T>  implements JsonDeserializer<T>{

   @Override
   public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
       JsonObject content = json.getAsJsonObject();
       String name = content.get("name").getAsString();
       Purity purity = Purity.valueOf(content.get("purity").getAsString());
       return new Gson().fromJson(content, typeOfT);
   }
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Possible JSON Example per request:

```
{
   "name" : "sword",
   "map" :
   {
      "map" :
      {
         "1,1,1" :  //string representation of Coord
         {
            "name" : "blade",
            "purity" : "base" // string representation of Purity Enum
         },
         "0,0,0" :
         {
            "name" : "handle",
            "purity" : "high"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you provide data sample(s)?

Comment: Updated post with possible JSON example. The contents of the inner "map" will never have fewer than 20 entries and can range up to 4,096. This information is only used on start up and on close.

Comment: did you try ```gson.fromJson(jsonStringData, YourClass.class)``` + ```@SerializedName```?

Comment: I have not, what does "+ @SerializedName" do

Comment: ```SerializedName``` resolves naming conflict between your POJO and incoming JSON data, i.e. name (your class) and "NaMe" (crazy json)

Comment: That sounds like it is for bad formatting of a json not serializing a structure.